# Can SQLAlchemy populate foreign key relationships without querying the database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I come from the .NET world where the ORM NHibernate can populate foreign key relationships by loading an object by id. Loading the object simply returns a proxy of that object with the identifier I specified. This is useful for populated relationships when I know the identifier exists as it doesn't need to query the database, thus saving many round trips.

Here is my scenario. I have a customer model that can be associated with one or more divisions. The divisions are statically stored in the database and can be associated with one or more customers, thus requiring me to model a many-to-many relationship. There's an REST API route in the form of `/api/v1/customers/123/divisions` where I POST JSON data in the form of a list of division id's, `{'division_ids': [1, 2, 3, 4]}`. In this instance (real-world usage could equate to 20+ division id's, I would be required to issue a query to fetch the customer (id 123) as well as 4 queries to fetch the divisions.

Since I know the id's of the divisions I want to insert, can I force SQLAlchemy to simply use the id's rather than fetch the objects?

Can SQLAlchemy do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, you can do so by using `lazy="dynamic"` in a relationship. [Docs:](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html)

> A key feature to enable management of a large collection is the so-called “dynamic” relationship. This is an optional form of relationship() which returns a Query object in place of a collection when accessed. filter() criterion may be applied as well as limits and offsets, either explicitly or via array slices:

Example tables:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", lazy="dynamic")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

When the Parent object is loaded, the children will not be loaded; instead a `Query` object will be loaded in its place, which can be used to access the children if desired.

```
p = session.query(Parent).first() # children will not be loaded here
print(type(p.children)) # <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderQuery'>
all_children = p.children.all() # conduct a query on the children query object
print(all_children) # [<__main__.Child object at 0x10ba3f908>, <__main__.Child object at 0x10ba3f978>]
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't very clear. I updated it with my exact scenario.